# To find the number of terms in a polynomial series product?

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials

The question asks me to find the number of terms in the polynomial product expansion :

$$
(1 + x^{-1})(1 + x^{-2})(1 + x^{-4})(1 + x^{-8})......(1 + x^{-2^{n}})
$$

I tried multiplying by $(1-x^{-1})$ to remove the terms in succession but I couldn't figure out what to do next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The product is $$\sum_{r=0}^{2\cdot2^n-1}x^{-r}$$

So, the number of term $=\displaystyle\sum_{r=0}^{2\cdot2^n-1}1=2\cdot2^n-1+1$